# JAudio feature exxtractor not extracting features for specific files

Tags: audio

I am using jAudio software for feature extraction of audio files. Im using filws in aiff,au,wav etc. file formats. It extracts features of file with frame rate of 16000 frmaes per second, channel:stereo, frame size: 16bit etc.
Though I have converters which convert file to wav, au, aiff formats but I donot have any converter which asks me frame rate etc. while converting. So I have files which have higher feature values and it gives error while converting.

Kindly guide is this software error or songs should be converted in this frame rate etc. only.

Kindly also suggest a software which converts audio file format asking these feature values while converting.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jAudio GUI, you can change the sample rate.

Here it is.. http://jmir.sourceforge.net/jAudio.html

Select `Analysis->Sample Rate->`

Answer (score 0):

Issue of Sample Rate does not cause error. Only thing you just follow is of that it must be in .wav format also the file size should be less than 35 MB.

Answer (score 0):

You are absolutely right - jAudio will throw exceptions if the sample rate or other audio file properties are not uniform in the input set. May I recommend SoX or gstreamer to preprocess your audio files to a single standard. That should eliminate the errors you are experiencing.